# Mathematical background for TQFT

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, homotopy-theory, quantum-field-theory

I am physicist. I`ve started studying Topological QFT.

What would you recommend to read in mathematical field for understanding Witten’s old articles of 80s-90s? 
What books/articles could help form proper mathematical background for TQFT?

Comment: It depends on which articles. The one on Chern-Simons theory freely manipulates a lot of differetial geometry and low-dimensional topology, especially knot theory and 3D manifolds. In other articles, on conformal field theory for example, algebraic and differential topology (characteristic classes) and complex analysis are used, and in papers on mirror symmetry algebraic geometry, Kähler manifolds, complex manifolds and their deformation theory are featured prominently. It's a big effort to master any of those.

Comment: I'm interested in basic mathematical foundations of Chern-Simons theory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we are talking *Quantum Field Theory and the Jones Polynomial* and *Chern–Simons Gauge Theory as a String Theory*. My advice is to start reading Witten and pick up background on what he uses as you go along, trying to learn all those mathematical theories in their entirety may be insurmountable.

Bar-Natan's [thesis](http://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/LOP.html#thesis) is a detailed interpretation of Witten's perturbative Chern–Simons theory by a mathematician, see also other papers on his website. It brought the theory of finite type or Vassiliev link invariants into prominence. For a more recent take look at Sawon's [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504495.pdf).

Freed's [survey](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0005032v1.pdf) is a nice segway from the Chern-Simons theory to modern mathematical TQFT. For Witten's non-perturbative approach the main mathematical ingredients are knots and links, skein relations, polynomial invariants, surgery on links that produces 3-manifolds, connections, holonomy and conformal blocks. The best introduction to knots is Adams' [Knot Book](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Knot_Book.html?id=M-B8XedeL9sC), it does cover Jones polynomial and skein relations, but to get into surgery you'll need [Rolfsen](http://books.google.com/books/about/Knots_and_Links.html?id=s4eGEecSgHYC). I am hoping that you know connections and holonomy (gauge theory) from the physical side, I liked this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444897089). Representation theory of semisimple Lie algebras/compact Lie groups, $SU(N)$ in particular (roots, weights, Weyl character formula, etc., see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0005032v1.pdf) for example or in this standard [text](http://books.google.com/books/about/Representations_of_Compact_Lie_Groups.html?id=AfBzWL5bIIQC)), should be more or less enough to understand Witten's use of conformal blocks. Conformal blocks themselves can be interpreted either in terms of bundles on the moduli of curves or of integrable representations of affine Lie algebras, but either path is very convoluted, perhaps references [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/a-pedestrian-explanation-of-conformal-blocks) will help.

However, reading Witten is different from learning (modern) mathematical foundations of Chern-Simons theory. Non-perturbative approach is based on quantum groups and graphic calculus of Reshetikhin-Turaev (which is a good thing to know since it's pretty universal to 2D TQFT), the standard reference is Turaev's [book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Quantum_Invariants_of_Knots_and_3_manifo.html?id=w7dActmezxQC), which also goes into TQFT in general, see also part II [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701568.pdf). Understanding quantum groups and computations with them also requires knowing representations of Lie groups.